# showing Facebook profile pic without revealing userId

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am building a Facebook app that has the ability for others to submit stories, and if they publish this story to "Everyone", then anyone, even people who aren't their friends, can see the story.  I want to add the user's profile pic to the story.  I know that you can access this via:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<userId>/picture
```

However, I **do not** want to expose the user's userId this way.  Someone could just view the source, see their userId in the src URL and then the person's privacy has just been compromised.

I want to hide the userId so that this type of privacy leakage is **NOT** possible.

Is there a way to do this, or is my only option to save a non-profile image for the user?

Comment: Isn't showing the user's picture already leaking their privacy?

Comment: I think the user's picture is harder to derive personal information from.  It's kind of like Zynga poker, where you can see the profile pic, but you can't see anything except the person's first name.  I would think it's harder to find out someone's personal information from just a profile pic alone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They will always be a way to identify a user from their profile pic, assuming they have one set and aren't just using the standard silhouette. The UID is part of the string that makes up our CDN urls for profile pics, so there's nothing that's 100% foolproof.

Your best course of action would likely be query the Facebook API and store the CDN URL directly from there before rendering - eg for me, querying

`https://graph.facebook.com/260300016?fields=picture` will return the URL for my current profile picture - `https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/203337_260300016_1473273891_q.jpg`

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll have to ask the users for their own image, or an option to use their Facebook profile pic if they don't mind exposing their user id.